# Alternative of Running Android apps while Intel Visualization technology is not supported

Tags: android, sdk, intel, virtualization

I have installed Android Studio. Now I am trying to install Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager (`intelhaxm-android.exe`) but i am getting the error

[image]

After this Error I tried all solutions which i can get on internet. like UNCHECKING the Hyper-V folder in **Enable or Disable Windows Resources** and restarting the system.

Then try to enable and install it and got this problem in pic below 
[image]

Visualization is enabled in BIOS as well.

I also have checked this  via `securable.exe` and got this

[image]

After all this I came to know as my knowledge that my computer don't have abilities for this.  While my computer is [Inspiron 14 (N4050)](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-14-intel-n4050/drivers)

Now What i suppose to do ? TO run Apps of android. I also dont have Android phone but I have Iphone. While I have done development of Android on the same this machine With Eclipse and SDK manager. ( A year ago)

Comment: You should try **ARM EABI v7a** at first. The HAXM *is* alternative. Also refer to my [answer for *External Emulator For Android Studio?*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31817436/3501958).